# How to find working hours in php?

Tags: php, mysql

My In time is 2014-03-18 15:03:49. and out time is 2014-03-19 10:04:19.
Here how can calculate the difference?

I have tried like below.

```
$inTime = date('2014-03-18 15:03:49');
$outTime = date('2014-03-19 10:04:19');
$tot = $inTime - $outTime;
```

It shows the output value in negative :(

Comment: use `$outTime - $inTime`.. you are differentiating a `big value from a small value`. than obviusly you will get `negative`..

Comment: How did you expect it to return positive value?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$inTime = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $outTime = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
    $interval = $inTime ->diff($outTime );
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');//difference in days
```

Answer (score 0):

You would convert to seconds first:

```
$intime = strtotime('2014-03-18 15:03:49');
$outtime = strtotime('2014-03-19 10:04:19');
$seconds = $outtime - $intime;

$hh = str_pad(floor($seconds/3600),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
$mm = str_pad(floor($seconds%3600/60),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
$ss = str_pad($seconds%60,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo $hh . ':' . $mm . ':' . $ss;
```

Answer (score 0):

the php `date` function is for formatting a unixtime as a string, so it's going to return a string, not a number

if you use php `strtotime` you'll get numeric valus you can add and subtract

```
$inTime = strtotime('2014-03-18 15:03:49');
$outTime = strtotime('2014-03-19 10:04:19');
$tot = $outTime - $inTime;
```

`$tot` will then be the difference in time, in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
$inTime = strtotime('2014-03-18 15:03:49');
$outTime = strtotime('2014-03-19 10:4:19');
$diff = $outTime - $inTime;


//convert to min and sec
$convert_min = $diff/60;
$convert_sec = $diff%  60;//seconds

//convert to hours and min
$convert_hr = floor($convert_min/60);//hours
$remainder = floor($convert_min % 60);//minutes
$total_visit =  $convert_hr.":".$remainder.":".$convert_sec; 
print_r($total_visit);
// Output will be 19:0:30 hours
```